# Which STL collection would match 2D collision detection best?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I'm working on the game in C++. Basically, the game is going to be a simulation of the world with some animals, plants, and of course a player itself (Animals move in random directions). I wanna do it to practice OPP, algorithm library, and work a little with collections from STL. I want to mention that I'm rewriting this project, and there is only one concern that keeps bothers me - Checking collisions. The game is going to be two-dimensional (only x,y coordinates).

Because if I keep my organisms in vector it's going to take a linear time to find if there are other organisms on these coordinates. When there is more organisms, this search takes a lot of time (seriously, for 400 animals their turn could take 20-30 seconds). So my question is, which STL collection would fit my problem best. Thank you in advance for your help.
Animals may die, their strength may be modified, and they can also create offsprings.

Comment: The standard library does not contain the spatial partitioning trees you need.

Comment: You had used "my problem" to describe your problem in your title. This is rather non-informative, much like the "Bad" examples of titles listed in [ask].

Comment: When you write "STL collection", do you really mean "standard container"? Not many people go looking for an implementation of STL now that most of STL has been incorporated into the C++ standard library. (I recall some parts of STL being left out of the standard library, but I don't remember which off the top of my head. Also, my memory might only apply to earlier C++ standards.)

Comment: While you have a lot of "fluff" details (not really pertinent to your question), you left out at least one important detail: what is the precision of your coordinates relative to the size of your pieces/organisms? If you are using floating-point coordinates, then some sort of spatial partitioning is likely desired. If, however, you are using integer coordinates, using a grid where pieces mostly occupy only one square, then you already have your partition and other possibilities open up (although I think I would still go for a Boost container instead of a standard one).

Comment: i was thinking about unordered map, where key would be some hash of coordinates, and I would just move animals to other keys whenever they move